# Why do we feel asleep at night?

Tags: human-biology

Why do we feel asleep at night mostly?
 I tried not to sleep but I could not resist my sleep at night.

Comment: You may be interested in [this Q&A about the evolution of sleep](http://biology.stackexchange.com//questions/324/why-did-the-process-of-sleep-evolve-in-many-animals-what-is-its-evolutionary-ad). Currently your question could be a book title. It's a tad broad.

Comment: Do you mean "feel sleepy" or "fall asleep"?  Some of it is simply habit: I tend not to feel sleepy until midnight or so, but when I've shifted my sleep pattern towards early rising (which requires a concerted effort :-)), I would start to feel sleepy earlier in the evening.